# How to split django apps if shared view

Tags: python, django

There is a common case I encounter, where I can't find a way to split apps.

The case is when a info of two models is related and needs to be in the same template

An example speaks 1000 words: (2 models - pages + comments).

```
# models.py
class Page(models.Model):
title = models.CharField()
content = models.TextField()  


class Comment(models.Model):
page = models.ForeignKey('Page')
content = models.TextField()


# url.py
...
url(r'^page/(?P<page_pk>\d+)/$', views.ViewPage, name='page-view-no-comments'),
url(r'^comment/(?P<comment_pk>\d+)/$', views.ViewComment, name='comment-view'),
url(r'^page-with-comments/(?P<page_pk>\d+)/$', views.ViewPageWithComments, name='page-view-with-comments'),
...


# views.py
def ViewPage(request, page_pk):
page = get_object_or_404(Page, pk=page_pk)
return render(request, 'view_page.html', {'page':page,})


def ViewComment(request, comment_pk):
comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_pk)
return render(request, 'view_comment.html', {'comment':comment})

def ViewPageWithComments(request, page_pk):
page = get_object_or_404(Page, pk=page_pk)
page_comments = Comment.objects.filter(page=page)
return render(request, 'view_page.html', {'page':page,'page_comments':page_comments'})
```

In this situation, splitting to `Page app` and `Comment app` is problematic, because they share a view (`ViewPageWithComments`) and url.

My options are:

1) Create an Ajax call to comments, which has crawling problems although Google might have fixed it lately.

2) Create a method of page that calls a method in the comments app that returns html with the comments content. If the method needs more arguments I also need to write a custom filter tag.

3) Decide not to split...

Am I missing something and there's another option? When would you prefer (1) vs (2) ?

Note - I created a very simple example to keep the problem general.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to split anything, you have the pages, and comments have a foreign key to that so you can just iterate over the pages comments

```
{% for page in pages %}
    {% for comment in page.comment_set.all %}
    {% endfor}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to be able to use the same template for a version of this page without comments you can just wrap the comment for loop in an `{% if show_comments %}` statement

Comment: Thx, but I specifically gave a very simple example to explain the general idea. Think about an app with 20 models instead. if you have an elaborate app, and you want to split, and the models share a view, how do you split?